# String comparison in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have try to match some conditions for

- each letter instance in a string may only participate in one match.
- if a letter instance can participate in either n1 or n2, it is to be counted towards n1.
- the two strings may or may not be of the same length.

I have try to match on the basis of these conditions bit still getting issue while testing for long string or odd string comparisons.

```
def matchval_not_pos(str1, str2)
  a1, a2 = str1.chars, str2.chars
  [a1.size, a2.size].min.times do |i|
    if a1[i] == a2[i]
      a1.delete_at(i)
      a2.delete_at(i)
    end
  end
  a1.reduce(0) do |t,c|
    i = a2.index(c)
    if i
      inc = 1
      a2.delete_at(i)
    else
      inc = 0
    end
    t + inc
  end
end


Some examples (str1, str2 -> n1,n2):

"abc", "abc" -> 3,0
"bca", "abc" -> 0,3
"aab", "abb" -> 2,0
"aab", "aba" -> 1,2
"abc", "aaa" -> 1,0
```

Comment: Can you add a set of example inputs and outputs?

Comment: I am able to get output as 1 but not as "3,0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you have two strings, `s1` and `s2`, from which you obtain two strings:

```
ss1 = s1[0,n]
ss2 = s2[0,n]
```

where

```
n = [s1.size, s2.size].min
```

and you want to know if the characters of `ss2` can be rearranged to equal `ss1`. If my understanding is correct, that would be true if and only if the following is true:

```
ss1.chars.sort == ss2.chars.sort
```

Example:

```
s1 = "ebcda"
s2 = "adcbefr"
n = [s1.size, s2.size].min       #=> 5 
ss1 = s1[0,n]                    #=> "ebcda" 
ss2 = s2[0,n]                    #=> "adcbe" 
ss1.chars.sort == ss2.chars.sort #=> true
```

Comment: thanks Cary i tried your code. In this how can i do it self tested.

Comment: Did I understand your question correctly? I don't know what you mean by "self tested".  If you mean testing to make sure the code works properly, it's best to use a testing framework like [rspec](http://rspec.info/) or [minitest](http://www.rubyinside.com/a-minitestspec-tutorial-elegant-spec-style-testing-that-comes-with-ruby-5354.html).

Comment: Ok Even i was confused about the comment 'self tested'.